# Fluentd can not parse nested json array in my record

Tags: fluentd

I'm new to fluentd and I would like to parse a nested JSON Array, As we all know A Fluentd event consists of 3 components: tag,time and record, and “message” data is an array in my record, Anyone who knows how to split them?

My messages look like:

`{“host”:“TVT7108",“path”:“SYSLOG”,“timeZone”:“-0400",“message”:[“N ,007D”,“N ,0083”,“N ,0085"]}`

Take the above record data as an example，because “message” array has 3 elements, so we’d like to split the “message” data to 3 parts like this,  could you have any solutions? thanks in advance.

`{“host”:“TVT7108",“path”:“SYSLOG”,“timeZone”:“-0400",“message”:“N ,007D”}`

`{“host”:“TVT7108",“path”:“SYSLOG”,“timeZone”:“-0400",“message”:“N ,0083"}`

`{“host”:“TVT7108",“path”:“SYSLOG”,“timeZone”:“-0400",“message”:“N ,0085"}`

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/wshihadeh/fluent-plugin-record-splitter.

Comment: Hi @Azeem I have tried this plugin just followed the guide but got a problem:  `2022-05-17 23:01:13 -0700 [error]: #0 fluent/log.rb:372:error: unexpected error error_class=SystemStackError error="stack level too deep" `  and when I  check the existing configuration using the `ulimit -n` command is 65536 on my machine.  I have no idea how to fix, do you have any solutions?  thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! That sounds like a bug. I haven't used this personally. You should [open an issue](https://github.com/wshihadeh/fluent-plugin-record-splitter/issues/new/choose) with all the details. Hopefully, you'll get a better response there.